# Получить имя пользователя ПК

Tags: javascript, linux, vue.js

Всем привет.
Знаю, что скорее всего ответ будет "такой возможности у js нет", но все же может кто-то каких-то мыслей подкинет :)

Нужно получить имя пользоватея ПК в Linux через JS или Vue.

Для чего это нужно...
На стороне сервера будет собираться конфиг для подключения рабочего софта. Через веб приложенгие пользователи его качают и запускают софтину. Конфиг же для софтины на линуксе должен лежать в опредленной директории, путь к которой лежит через папку пользователя.
Соответственно нужно знать имя, чтобы корректно для каждого пользователя указывать адрес к папке.

Может кто знает как такое можно реализовать ?

Comment: «такой возможности у js нет» Но скорее всего и не надо. Т.к. есть вполне общеизвестные переменные окружения типа `$HOME` в *nix и `%userprofile%` в windows.

Comment: Папки, которые обычно используются для хранения пользовательских конфигов, могут быть перенесены за пределы домашней папки пользователя по его желанию. Вы уверены, что вам нужно получить именно папку пользователя, а не папку конфигов?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, верно. Первая мысль и было - использовать переменнве среды. Но... Скрипты на машине пользователя запускать никто не даст, чтобы просто скриптом собрать конфиг. А из веб морды переменные среды не достать. В этом и проблема :(

Comment: @andreymal путь к конфигу таков : /home/${USER}/.config/linphone . Я не знаток линукса. Не знаю как тут можно "упростить" задачу

Comment: Значит вам скорее всего нужен `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, что-то вроде https://www.npmjs.com/package/xdg-basedir (но это естественно для nodejs)

Comment: А из веб морды вам в принципе никто не даст доступ к файловой системе, так что и задача ваша не имеет смысла

Comment: Эм «и запускают софтину». Так пусть эта софтина переменные читает.

Comment: Я так понимаю - у тебя в твоём проекте есть привязка "комп Васи - ставим FF и VSCode"?

Comment: @andreymal, ну как не даст. Технически, получить доступ можно. Причём к любой папке. Причём на бесконтрольный доступ на чтение и запись. Юзеру нужно только будет выбрать папку на растерзание и нажать "даю доступ"